# How might I count the occurrence of a specific character that is different in every row

Tags: python, pandas, count

I would like to count how often a specific character (that is different in every row) appears in a dataframe series. Example dataframe:

| givenletter | phrase |
| --- | --- |
| w | whatwhatwhat |
| q | queenbee |
| d | devildonkey |
| n | woohoo |
| e | arrogant |

Desired result:

| givenletter | phrase | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| w | whatwhatwhat | 3 |
| q | queenbee | 1 |
| d | devildonkey | 2 |
| n | woohoo | 0 |
| e | arrogant | 0 |

Attempted code below just came back as 0 for all frequencies

```
df["frequency"] = df["phrase"].str.count(str(df["givenletter"]))
```

I've tried digging through similar stackoverflow questions but they all seem to deal with counting the occurrence of a character that doesn't change. Would be grateful for any advice on how I might correct my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df['frequency'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['phrase'].count(x['givenletter']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension is sufficient for this:

```
df["frequency"] = [phrase.count(letter) 
                   for phrase, letter 
                   in zip(df.phrase, df.givenletter)]
df    

    givenletter   phrase    frequency
0       w       whatwhatwhat    3
1       q       queenbee        1
2       d       devildonkey     2
3       n       woohoo          0
4       e       arrogant        0
```